# connection to blacklisted host DNSBL

Tags: ubuntu, dns, postfix, smtp, mailx

I’m trying to build a mail server, but when I tried to check the if TCP Port 25 (outbound) is blocked or not

I got the following

```
root@mail:~# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google .com 25
Trying 74.125.71.27…
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google .com.
Escape character is ‘^]’.
421 service not available (connection to blacklisted host (74.125.71.27 - DNSBL))
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I googled it, I found that DNSBL Stands For Domain Name System Blacklist

I checked port 25 For My Public IP Address https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports

And found it’s opened, I also checked the following websites to see if my Public IP Address is blacklisted

https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

http://www.dnsbl.manitu.net

https://check.spamhaus.org

https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php

But found that it's not blacklisted

I also did telnet from another server in another location to my server on port 25 and it could connect successfully

Now what should I do ?

Edit : When I tried to send email to my gmail account, I found that In the logs

**root@mail:~# journalctl -f _SYSTEMD_UNIT=postfix@-.service**

> Jun 07 06:49:44 mail.example.com postfix/smtp[4510]: AF3EE62218: lost
> connection with gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.26] while
> receiving the initial server greeting
>
> Jun 07 06:49:47 mail.example.com postfix/smtp[4510]: AF3EE62218: host
> alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.9.27] refused to talk to me:
> 421 service not available (connection to blacklisted host
> (142.251.9.27 - DNSBL))

> Jun 07 06:53:47 mail.example.com postfix/smtp[4510]: AF3EE62218: lost
> connection with alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.26] while
> receiving the initial server greeting

> Jun 07 06:55:47 mail.example.com
> postfix/smtp[4510]: AF3EE62218: to=ahmed@gmail.com,
> relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.157.26]:25, delay=729,
> delays=245/0.04/484/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection
> with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.157.26] while receiving
> the initial server greeting)

Comment: Your IP is 74.125.71.27?

Comment: No, when I checked this ip address in https://www.abuseipdb.com, I found that it belongs to Google

Comment: You know there's a typo in the google host address? That space shouldn't be there

Comment: Your question seems to be confusing remote hosts connecting to your server, and your server connecting to Google's SMTP service. You can't test one by doing the other.

Comment: @roaima No there's not a typo in the google host address, I just copied it from the terminal, but sure I've written the google host address many many time, and every time it gives me another different blacklisted IP Address

Comment: Ahmed Monem there is a typo; this command _cannot_ work, `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google .com 25`

Comment: @roaima I've fixed it `root@mail:~# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`
Trying 142.251.9.27...
Connected to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
421 service not available (connection to blacklisted host (142.251.9.27 - DNSBL))
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: @roaima Can you please check the logs that I've added to the post